# How to check if target element is intersecting with root element from another function?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have an Intersection Observer callback function that calls another function to fetch images:

```
function callback(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        getImages();
    });
}
```

But I want to check from inside the `getImages()` if the targeted element is still visible in the root element (viewport in my case), so that if it's still in the viewport, I want to call the `getImages()` again and fetch more images until the targeted element is not intersecting (Because on initial load there can happen a situation where not enough images are loaded and the target element is always in the viewport and not updating anymore)

Can I get the current state from within the `getImages()` function?

```
function getImages() {
    ... append images to some div ...

    // if (target element still intersecting with root element) {
    // getImages();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API ? *[...] Implementing intersection detection in the past involved event handlers and loops calling methods like `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` [...]*

Comment: yes I read it. So you say I should use `getBoundingClientRect`?

Comment: @tevemadar I ended up using `getBoundingClientRect` on the target element and check if it's in the viewport every time I append new images. Is that what you meant? It does seem to work though I'm not sure it's the proper way

Comment: Technically you get callbacks for all changes, so you can just store them in some `Map` perhaps, and you would get updates while the images load and user scrolls away and the like. Then you can look at that `Map` whenever you need it, and know if the element is still visible or something. However `getBoundingClientRect` still exists, and if you just want to use it for a known element, that's probably simpler and more efficient in code than some track-all-intersection-updates magic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [IntersectionObserver.isIntersecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/isIntersecting) property to determine if the target element is intersecting with the root element.

**Example:**

```
// Create a new Intersection Observer to watch for when an element enters or exits the viewport
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

// Callback function to execute when an element enters/exits the viewport
function callback(entries, observer) {
    // Loop through each entry
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        // Call the getImages() function when an element enters/exits the viewport
        getImages();
    });
}

// Function to fetch and append images
function getImages() {
    // Fetch and append images to some div
    ...

    // If the target element is still intersecting with the root element
    if (observer.isIntersecting) {
        // Call the getImages() function again
        getImages();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `undefined` in this location. Only if pass it to the function from the `callback` it works: `getImages(entry.isIntersecting)`, but then it means its value is not updated.

Comment: Also it's weird because while I append images, it means the targeted element is moving so it needs to call the `callback` function again but it only call it once

Comment: The callback function will be called again each time the targeted element is intersecting with the viewport. The only time it won't be called is when the element is not intersecting with the viewport. In this case, you may need to manually call the callback function to make sure the observer.isIntersecting property is updated. `observer.observe(element);`

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about manually calling the observer, but is it possible to do that? I thought that it's like a listener so it's not that I can manually call it because it's listening to changes. As a workaround for now though, what I did was to use `getBoundingClientRect` to determine if the target element is in viewport and load more images if not. Will also try the manually calling the `callback`, though not sure what syntax is correct for that

Comment: Using getBoundingClientRect is a good approach, and it should work fine. You can also try manually calling the observer callback, as described above. - The main difference is that manually calling the observer callback will allow you to trigger the callback at any time, while using getBoundingClientRect will only trigger the callback when the target element is within the viewport.